# Save Android Resource Image to Disk in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm looking to save an image from Android resources (e.g., "Resources/drawable/a.jpg") to the device's storage in a Xamarin project. Seeking guidance on the most effective approach for accomplishing this task.

Details:

Tried using Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.OpenRawResource but encountered issues.
Any recommendations on saving an Android resource image to disk in Xamarin?
Appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!